# MySQL Attendance System

Tags: mysql

I have made an attendance system for a project, However I'm stuck right now  by trying to create a query.

```
SELECT
COUNT(Students.idStudents) total,
SUM(case when Attendance.status LIKE 'present' then 1 else 0 end) present,
SUM(case when Attendance.status LIKE 'late' then 1 else 0 end) late,
SUM(case when Attendance.status is null then 1 else 0 end) absents
FROM Students, Schools, Tags LEFT JOIN Attendance 
ON Attendance.tagCode = Tags.tagCode
WHERE Schools.idSchools = Students.idSchools
AND Tags.idStudents = Students.idStudents
```

This code works and generates an attendance. However this will show all the dates.

When I add in another line to specify date

```
AND Attendance.date = DATE(NOW());
```

It will not show anything..

There's 'Present', 'Late' status for the attendance however if the student's record in that table doesn't exist, it is considered as absent.

How do I do that?

[image: ERD]

Comment: first things first, you probably shouldn't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. in fact... you should just never use implicit at all.

Comment: Welp, guess no one can help solve this, multi-query time.

Comment: noone can help based on your lack of table definitions or sample data.

Comment: No one really told me they needed alot more information
Mainly i just need to find a way to get all student's daily attendance even if it doesn't exist in the attendance table.

Comment: Is it possible to get a little bit of sample data there - just enough to show someone who was late, someone who was on time, and someone who didnt show at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a case insensitive collation, your purported solution can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.idStudents) total
     , SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) present -- [or just SUM(a.status = 'present')]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 'late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) late
     , SUM(CASE WHEN a.status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) absents
  FROM Students p
  JOIN Schools s
    ON s.idSchools = p.idSchools
  JOIN Tags t
    ON t.idStudents = p.idStudents
  LEFT 
  JOIN Attendance a 
    ON a.tagCode = t.tagCode
   AND a.date = CURDATE() ;
```

For next time: Your ERD shows 10 tables, but only 4 feature in this problem. If a table isn't likely to be part of the proposed solution, don't show it. Don't provide pictures. Instead, where possible, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle), TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET based upon a minimal, but properly representative data set.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, I'm not that 'good' with MySQL and this project has already gave me quite a problem, but indeed i'm new here and thanks! I'll heel your advice. ><

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
SELECT
COUNT(Students.idStudents) total,
SUM(case when Attendance.status LIKE 'present' then 1 else 0 end) present,
SUM(case when Attendance.status LIKE 'late' then 1 else 0 end) late,
SUM(case when Attendance.status is null then 1 else 0 end) absents
FROM Students, Schools, Tags LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE Attendance.date = NOW()) AS Attendance
ON Attendance.tagCode = Tags.tagCode
WHERE Schools.idSchools = Students.idSchools
AND Tags.idStudents = Students.idStudents
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. This is a recipe for disaster. In fact don't use implicit join syntax at all. It was effectively superseded in 1992 - when Dan Quayle was Vice President

Comment: How do i make it not the case? I can't find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original query was you were asking for students where their attendance was "NOW" where no student was ever now but they are current attending classes. They may have signed in at 8am and you run the query at 10am. You'd need to manipulate the datetime to choose your start time and end time based on the current day.

timestampadd(HOUR, 08, CURDATE()) - this will give you 8am, you'd then query for when attendance.date is greater than or equal to 8am and then potentially less than or equal to 4pm?